# Unit test failing after moving functions into a class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function within a class but I'm having a little trouble. Before moving the importer function into a class, this test worked. However, now I get `TypeError: grab_column_locations missing 1 required positional argument: 'sheet'`. The importer function itself is correctly getting parsing `sheet` and works correctly when the program is run, but not when tested.

The line the TypeError refers to in the importer function is:

```
columns = self.grab_column_locations(sheet)
```

The test that's failing is:

```
from unittest import TestCase

from gtt import GTT


class TestGTT(TestCase):

    def test_importer(self):
        """
        Test import of valid xlsx file
        :return:
        """

        file_list = ['testData_1.xls']

        # Run Test 1
        importer_results = GTT.importer(GTT, file_list)
        assert importer_results[0] == True
```

So essentially, when run from a test, `importer`isn't passing `sheet`to `grab_column_locations`. This only started happening when I moved both of those functions into a class. I know I broke something somehow, but what?

Comment: What is your directory structure like? Also what does the grab_column_locations function look like?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says this:

```
TypeError: grab_column_locations missing 1 required positional argument: 'sheet'
```

This sounds like the function signature is:

```
def grab_column_locations(self, sheet):
```

Are you not calling it from an **instance** of the class owning this function?

That is, if the function belongs to the class `Foo`:

```
class Foo:
    def grab_column_locations(self, sheet):
        ...
```

The error message makes me think that you're calling the function as follows:

```
Foo.grab_column_locations(sheet)
```

When you really should call it:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.grab_column_locations(sheet)
```

Alternatively, that function could be defined as a **class** method, if you don't want to bind it to an **instance**:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def grab_column_locations(self, sheet):
        ...
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
Foo.grab_column_locations(sheet)
```

But anyway, this is just guesswork, since you didn't give much details.